# Windowphone 8.1 change code to async task

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8.1

I want to read an XML file and bind data of it to a listbox.

In page1, click button and go to page2.

In page2, listbox binding data from xml file.

This is code for get data from xml file:

```
class GetData
{
    public object obj_get_data(string xml_file)
    {
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(xml_file);
        var list_emp = from query in xdoc.Descendants("emp")
                        select new du_lieu.thong_tin
                        {
                            Name = (string)query.Element("age"),
                            Age = (string)query.Element("age"),
                        };
        return list_emp;
    }
}
```

In page2, on `NavigationHelper_LoadState` I write this code to binding data:

```
private void NavigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
{            
    GetData gd = new GetData();
    object obj = gd.obj_get_data(xml_danh_sach);
    listbox1.ItemsSource = obj;
}
```

With this code, everything is ok,
but, when click button on page1, app delay some second before go to page2.

I know I need working on that with async task and progess bar/ring to make app
like normal,
but I don't know do to do it.
Can everyone help me?

Comment: Is this WPF or Windows Phone? Your tag says one thing, your title says another. In any case, there are lots of posts on Stack Overflow showing how to wrap synchronous code in `Task.Run()` to make an asynchronous implementation. What have you looked at already? What have you tried? What _specifically_ did you have trouble with? Please provide a good [mcve] showing all this and explain precisely what's giving you difficulty.

Comment: @PeterDuniho : In windows phone 8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
class GetData
{
    public async Task<object> obj_get_data(string xml_file)
    {
        XDocument xdoc = await XDocument.Load(xml_file);
        var list_emp = from query in xdoc.Descendants("emp")
                        select new du_lieu.thong_tin
                        {
                            Name = (string)query.Element("age"),
                            Age = (string)query.Element("age"),
                        };
        return list_emp;
    }
}
```

And this:

```
private async Task NavigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
{            
    GetData gd = new GetData();
    object obj = await gd.obj_get_data(xml_danh_sach);
    listbox1.ItemsSource = obj;
}
```